# I want to Split an String in if_then_else format in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I want to parse an string given in following format:

STRING : `if( (a==10) && (b==20) && (c==30) && ((d==40) && (e==50)))`

OUTPUT : `[ "a==10","b==20","c==30","(d==40) &&(e==50)" ]`

What is the best way to achieve the same in Javascript .

I'm not that familiar with regular expressions .

Comment: What have you attempted? Stack Overflow is meant to help with specific code problems, not produce a full solution given some requirements.

Comment: Also there seems to be a discrepancy in your expected output. Is it a typo: `&&`?

Comment: do you want to to convert if( (a==10) && (b==20) && (c==30) && ((d==40) && (e==50))) to [ "a==10","b==20","c==30","(d==40) &&(e==50)" ] ??

Comment: @andy : All i want is all first level blocks inside IF to be splitted. IF ( (condition1) && (condition2) && (condition3) && (condition4 && condition5)) then i want an array containing [condition1,condition2,condition3,(condition4 && condition5)]

Comment: @ajp15243 : i dont need full solution, i just need pointers how to write such reg ex , actual problem is way more complex , just needed some starting point . Sry if question is too naive !!

Answer (score 1):

```
var match = str.match(/[a-z]==[0-9]{2,}/g);
```

This assumes that the sequence will always be a single letter followed by two equals signs followed by a number greater than 10.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6T3TQ/)